# How to change my local sql server sa password?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am a local administrator on my computer, how can I change the sa password of my local installation of sql server 2008?

**Note: I don't know the password for the sa account**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover sa password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475970/recover-sa-password)

Answer (score 3):

A truly late response for the thread, but I just lost and reset password for SA.

Follow below easy steps and you are done:

1. Connect SQL Server in Window's Authentication Mode.
2. Now Go to **Security** and explore it.
3. Go to **Login** under **Securrity**.
4. Select the user **sa**
5. **Right Click** on **sa** and select **Properties**
6. You will get reset password option here, change it and log-in with
   new password again.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

One way

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD=N'NewPassword'
GO
```

You can also go to security, right click on ss, select properties and change it in the password field

Comment: Or for the old-schoolers `EXEC sp_password N'old password', N'new password', N'sa';`

Comment: SqlMenace, I tried your way...I get this: Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.  (Looking in logins, I can see the sa user.)

Comment: Login as the sa and do it like that, btw you inspired me to create this post http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/how-to-change-the-sa  :-)

Comment: I don't know the sa's password, how can I login? your joking right? :)(

Comment: I wasn't joking, I though you just wanted to change the sa password, what are you login in as? Windows authentication? what permissions do you have?

Comment: Yes windows authentication, I am a local admin on windows 7.

Comment: What are your permissions for SQl Server?