# Recover sa password

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a computer which was used by another employee.

SQL Server 2008 R2 was installed but I don't know the 'sa' password.

When I try to alter the login, it gives below error.

> Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

When I try to restore a database, it gives a different permission error.

(When I enter the Security --> Logins --> sa --> Properties 
windows authentication is disabled.)

Can I change it?

P.S: Password is not "password" :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way I can retrieve sa password in sql server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196150/is-there-a-way-i-can-retrieve-sa-password-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The best way is to simply reset the password by connecting with a domain/local admin (so you may need help from your system administrators), but this only works if SQL Server was set up to allow local admins (these are now left off the default admin group during setup).

If you can't use this or other existing methods to recover / reset the SA password, some of which are explained here:

- [Disaster Recovery: What to do when the SA account password is lost in SQL Server 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20191007012923/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulga/2007/07/13/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005/)
- [Is there a way I can retrieve sa password in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196150/is-there-a-way-i-can-retrieve-sa-password-in-sql-server-2005)
- [How to recover SA password on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2](http://v-consult.be/2011/05/26/recover-sa-password-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2/)

Then you could always backup your important databases, uninstall SQL Server, and install a fresh instance.

You can also search for less scrupulous ways to do it (e.g. there are password crackers that I am not enthusiastic about sharing).

As an aside, the login properties for `sa` would never say Windows Authentication. This is by design as this is a SQL Authentication account. This does not mean that Windows Authentication is disabled at the instance level (in fact it is not possible to do so), it just doesn't apply for a SQL auth account.

I wrote a tip on using [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to connect to an instance using the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account (which works < SQL Server 2012), and a follow-up that shows how to hack the SqlWriter service (which can work on more modern versions):

- [Recover access to a SQL Server instance](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [More on Recovering Access to a SQL Server Instance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4672/more-on-recovering-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

And some other resources:

- [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out)
- [Leveraging Service SIDs to Logon to SQL Server Instances with Sysadmin Privileges](https://www.0xsql.com/2012/01/12/leveraging-service-sids-to-logon-to-sql-server-2012-2014-and-new-2016-instances-with-sysadmin-privileges/)

Comment: PSExec trick worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

best answer written by [Dmitri Korotkevitch](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/16706dec-209f-42c4-8dc7-4ee4dd5df482/):

> Speaking of the installation, SQL Server 2008 allows you to set
>   authentication mode (Windows or SQL Server) during the installation
>   process. You will be forced to choose the strong password for sa user
>   in the case if you choose sql server authentication mode during setup.
>
> If you install SQL Server with Windows Authentication mode and want to
>   change it, you need to do 2 different things:
>
> 1. Go to SQL Server Properties/Security tab and change the mode to SQL Server authentication mode
> 2. Go to security/logins, open SA login properties
>
> a. Uncheck "Enforce password policy" and "Enforce password expiration"
>   check box there if you decide to use weak password
>
> b. Assign password to SA user
>
> c. Open "Status" tab and enable login.
>
> I don't need to mention that every action from above would violate
>   security best practices that recommend to use windows authentication
>   mode, have sa login disabled and use strong passwords especially for
>   sa login.

Comment: I don't think this helps. The server is already set to mixed mode authentication. And the user doesn't have the privilege necessary to change the sa password, hence the question being posted here in the first place.

Comment: I tried it but it gives cannot alter the 'sa' because of permission error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24246285/1957479