# How can I reset a forgotten sa password?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL server 2008 r2. When I was installing, I had chosen the mixed mode of SQL authentication.

I have given `sa` as user name and given some password then I forgot the password.

I don't know how to change the user password or delete that and create new user log-in?

Comment: When installing a ms sql server it is not advisable the `mixed mode` option for beginner.

Comment: Are you able to login to your SQL server?

Comment: Flagged to be migrated to [**dba@stackexchange.com**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq), where you can get better answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover sa password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475970/recover-sa-password)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
exec sp_password null, '<new password>', 'sa'
```

Run this as a sysadmin user, substituting  with whatever new password you want.

Comment: FYI sp_password is depreciated.  They recommend using ALTER LOGIN now since sp_password will be going away soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you can log into your system as a sysadmin then run the following.

```
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = 'xx'
```

If you can't log in as the sysadmin but can at least log into the server as an administrator let me know and I'll send you a link on how to fix your problem.

Comment: I found the link anyway.  Go to SQLSkills here: http://www.sqlskills.com/insidercontent/insidernewsletters.asp.  You may have to sign up as a "SQL Skills Insider" to get there, I'm not sure.  Either way if you look at the October 29th, 2012 edition it has a video on connecting to your instance sysadmin.