# Creating databases and tables in ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, authentication, permissions, ssms

I just installed ssms on my local computer.

When I try to create a database or a database table it gives me an error stating that I don't have the right permissions. I tried granting permissions for this user by going to `Security->Logins->myUser`. But again it told me I didn't have the right permissions. I then tried adding a new login/user which gave me the same error.

What can I do to give myself the correct permissions if I installed the ssms and there are no other users except `sa`, which has "login with this user" disabled by default. I can't login as another user and I can't change my current user permissions. VERY CONFUSED - someone please help!

Comment: SQL Database instance you are trying to connecting at which machine? I mean is it local or are you trying to connect a server?

Comment: local right on my machine!

Comment: adreanbanks - can you please explain - I installed my ssms on my local computer to connect to a  local instance - where does your answer come in?

Comment: SSMS is asking for which ever user installed sql server on your local machine, not SSMS. If you think that was you it doesn't agree. You could try and recover, or you could just uninstall and re-install, or if it's used and you just can't get at it. Install another Instance as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the installation you (or somebody else) had to add an user besides the SA to login with Windows authentication. Use this user.

Your user is a simple user that does not have enough permissions.

If you are not the guy who installed the server, ask whoever installed this to set the right permission for your user.

Also please check [recover-sa-password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475970/recover-sa-password) and [Disaster Recovery: What to do when the SA account password is lost in SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should check that you are placing the files in a folder where the SQL Server account (not the one you are logging on as, but the service account) has rights to write.

For starters, **and not to be kept in a production environment**, try to make sure that the default path for placing the database files has Read/Write set to Everyone.